# Using an array to populate if statement values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to toggle a css style to a couple elements on using an `if statement`.  I have it working by using many `if statements`, but I feel like it can be simplified using an array with the values and one `if statement`.

Here is what I have working so far:

```
var linkValues =  $("#links-active-picker").val() && $("#links-panel-picker").val();

if(linkValues == "#009bd1"){
    $("#light-blue").parent().addClass("selected");
}

if(linkValues == "#0bdea1"){
    $("#light-green").parent().addClass("selected");
}  

if(linkValues == "#edd531"){
    $("#yellow").parent().addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: what is this? `var linkValues =  $("#links-active-picker").val() && $("#links-panel-picker").val();`

Comment: Provide the full code. Create a jfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a simple object

```
var obj = {
    "#009bd1": "#light-blue",
    "#0bdea1": "#light-green", 
    "#edd531": "#yellow"
};
```

and then do

```
if (obj[linkValues]) {
    $(obj[linkValues]).parent().addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: Adam - Thank you so much.  This works perfectly, I was thinking either this or an array.  This is much cleaner and works well for many cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    "#009bd1": "#light-blue",
    "#0bdea1": "#light-green", 
    "#edd531": "#yellow"
};

if(linkValues in obj){
   $(obj[linkValues].parent().addClass('selected');
}
```